# how to send a whole sheet using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, attachment

Trying to send the contents of a sheet1, A:R using the MailApp.sendEmail. I can't seem to figure out how to get the data to break after each row

I've tried to define the range based on last row and column

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MissingInfo");
var Row = sheet.getLastRow()
var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,Row,Col);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
var emailAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
var message = data
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

This works, except the data, doesn't break at the end of each row. any ideas on how to have a line break?

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a 2D array. You can join row arrays using newlines `\n`:

```
var message = data.join('\n');
```